# How to interpret access log of Apache server?

Tags: http, apache2.2, access-log

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log) link but could understand as they have provided with a different format.

This is an entry in my access log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2012:13:39:53 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 48
```

I want to know the meaning of the last code.
I know that 200 id OK status code but what is 48 or any other number.... ?

Please help!

Comment: %b is the size of the response to the client (in bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it means the size in bytes ..

Regards

mimiz