# Apache Log files; numbers on the end; not status code & response size

Tags: apache, logging

This is an addition to: [Understanding Apache's access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log)

I have an Apache log file with the following (this is from an example data set on the Splunk website):

`178.19.3.35 - - [19/Oct/2013:15:23:00] "GET /flower_store/product.screen?product_id=FL-DLH-02 HTTP/1.1" 200 10582 "http://mystore.splunk.com/flower_store/category.screen?category_id=CANDY&JSESSIONID=SD3SL8FF9ADFF9" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.10) Gecko/20070223 CentOS/1.5.0.10-0.1.el4.centos Firefox/1.5.0.10" 2258 3329`

What is not explained in the above post or in the Apache log help is the `2258 3329` at the very end of this block. What do those numbers mean?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common may be useful reference. After 200 is probably the size of the file being downloaded. The two final numbers, I'm not sure..

Comment: You can verify the number after 200 is the file size by downloading the file, and then check how large the file is

Answer (score 1):

Log file format can be customized in almost any way, so the only way to be sure what those numbers might mean is to check the server configuration.

1. Open `httpd.conf`
2. Find `LogFormat`
3. Check [Format Strings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) for the meaning

Comment: Unfortunately, because this is sample data there is actually no httpd.conf