# Apache access log

Tags: apache

I want to ask what does the last number on each request in the access log mean?

`127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2014:12:49:31 +0300] "GET /battleWS/startServer/11 HTTP/1.1" 200 159`

In this case it is `159`, occasionally it's empty `-` (dash). Can someone tell me what this is? Thanks!

Comment: It's the size of the object returned to the client in bytes.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but the fact that scripts are shown as `-` made me think twice. Thanks and why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Because then I'd have to go and find some links to the documentation and I couldn't be bothered. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says:
(%b) The last part indicates the size of the object returned to the client, not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be "-". To log "0" for no content, use %B instead.

The reason you see a "-" is because it asks if the resource has changed since last time, so it doesn't actually fetch it again.

Google is a lot faster than SO for such simple questions. :)

Comment: Oh did I try. I don't know why I'm having such a hard time with `apache` and `mysql` documentation :X

Answer (score 1):

The last number which is returned on the apache log in the object size which is returned to the client ..

Understand more about the acces log [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log)