# Jira to know how many poeple have visited an issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

I want to know how many people have visited a particular isssue in order to know its popularity( I can't trust on number of watchers of the issue) .Is there any way (JiraDB or anything) by which i can know how many people(just the count) have visited any particular issue.

The question can be modified like this : Top 10 mostly visited issues in a week or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seb's earlier answer provides a possible solution for JIRA Cloud. I am not aware of any off-the-shelf product for behind-the-firewall installations of JIRA, and I do not believe that views are tracked anywhere in the JIRA database.

For behind-the-firewall instances, you could certainly write a script to parse the JIRA access logs (stored in $JIRA_HOME/logs/access_log*) to count issue accesses that way.

The JIRA access logs are stored in a format that is similar to the [Apache access log format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log), so you just need to parse out accesses to individual issues by looking for URLs of the format "http://MYJIRA/browse/ABC-123".

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this is not possible. Jira does not log view counts for single issues.

You could have a look if there is any plugin for this at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=jira

E.g. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/communardo.connect.usage.statistic.addon looks like it could fit your requirements, but I personally have never heard of it.