# Understanding Apache Access Log format

Tags: apache, access-log

I would like to understand more about Apache access log format.

This is an additional question to [Understanding Apache's access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log)

Based on my log below,

> 27.111.34.139 - - [02/Sep/2015:03:50:47 +0800] "GET /&page=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00 HTTP/1.1" 404 248 "-" "Mozilla/9.0(X11; Linux x819_68) blog.inurl.com.br/eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/179.31" 70 0

As you can see that there are additional **70** & **0** at the end of the string.

What does 70 & 0 mean at the end of the string?

Does this occurred because of certain user-agent used or request or other specific parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log/30108140#30108140

Answer (score 1):

70 is request size and 0 is the response size (in this case no response as the returned code is 404)