# http response code followed by a number

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a python bottle framework webservice that is running on my localmachine.

It is working fine but when I see the console, I see a number followed by the response status code. In the below line what is the number 166 followed by 200.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 17:34:50] "POST /tensorservice HTTP/1.1" 200 166
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about an application layer protocol, not software programming

Comment: What a bad question, you didn't even tell us which framework you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the size of the response to the client (bytes sent).

I think it is the standard format of `wsgi` logs and the exact details of each of the fields are discussed in [Understanding Apache's access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apaches-access-log)